# delegates and gestureRecognizers for a UIView Subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create a UIView class that acts like a button. I want to do it entirely programmatically. I am able to get the button to appear but it is not clicking properly.

In my classes implementation file I have an initialization method as well as the following:

```
- (void)handlePress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        NSLog(@"in handlePress");
    }
}
```

In my view controller implementation file I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.button = [[buttonclass alloc] initButton];
    [self.view addSubview: self.button];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *singlePress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
    [self.button.buttonView addGestureRecognizer:singlePress];
}
```

(button being the instance variable of the class buttonclass and buttonView is just a subview of button)

I'm pretty sure the problem is within the lines:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *singlePress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
    [self.button.buttonView addGestureRecognizer:singlePress];
```

I'm not even sure if these lines should go within the button initialization function or in the view controller implementation file. Should I add the following line?

```
singlePress.delegate = self;
```

I tried adding that line but I do not know where to put it and an error is saying that the `delegate` and `self` aren't the same type. Regardless, something is going wrong when I try to hook up the GestureRecognizer to the action or when I'm hooking the GestureRecognizer to the UIView button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: is this class a subclass of UIButton?

Comment: no it is a subclass of UIView

Comment: See @Apurv's answer below, because that's what I was going to say as well. In addition, I'd encourage you to look at subclassing UIButton or UIControl and simply overriding the methods you need to. You will pick up a lot of functionality without having to code everything by hand.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose Its better to derive from UIControl class when you want to give your own implementation for a particular control. UIButton is also an extension of UIControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the gesture on button and not on to the subview of button.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *singlePress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:singlePress];
```

There is no need to add following line:

```
singlePress.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Haha, I can't believe that it was just a layer issue. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

In addition dont forget to release the Button object otherwise you will get an memory leak maybe in case you forget to clean up...

```
[super viewDidLoad];

self.button = [[buttonclass alloc] initButton];
[self.view addSubview: self.button];
[self.button release];
```

regards